# MongoDb: how to search in multiple collections?

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

I got this structure in my mongodb (2 collections: `restaurant` and `cocktail`)

```
restaurant {id=1001, name="Res1", coor=[12.392, 19.123], cocktail=[13, 0, 92]}

cocktail {id=13, name="Capiroska"}, {id=167, name="Capirinha"}, {id=92, name="Negroni"}, {id=0, name="Martini"}
```

Multiple `restaurant`s and multiple `cocktail`s, N:N relationship.

My goal is to find which different `cocktail`s I can drink within a specified area.

I've already written a query that finds all restaurants near my position like this:

```
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("address.location").withinSphere(new Circle(latitude, longitude, radius/6371))
            ), Restaurant.class);
```

So that I obtain a list of `restaurant`s.

Next steps are:

1. How to obtain distinct `cocktail`'s `id` (no repetitions allowed)
2. How to look into `cocktail` collection in order to obtain all `cocktail` names

TY in advance!

Comment: This might help you: https://engineering.universe.com/mongo-aggregations-in-5-minutes-b8e1d9c274bb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not answer your question completely but can help

**how to obtain distinct cocktails id (no repetitions allowed)**

Your `cocktail` is in array so direct `group` or `distinct` might not work you can use `$unwind`.

> What $unwind does is allow you to peel off a document for each element
>   and returns that resulting document

eg: for this object

```
{id=1001, name="Res1", coor=[12.392, 19.123], cocktail=[13, 0, 92]}
```

and this query

```
db.temp.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$cocktail" } ] )
```

will result in

```
{ "_id" : 1001, "name" : "Res1", coor=[12.392, 19.123],, "cocktail" : 13 }
{ "_id" : 1001, "name" : "Res1", coor=[12.392, 19.123],, "cocktail" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 1001, "name" : "Res1", coor=[12.392, 19.123],, "cocktail" : 92 }
```

Now once you have all individual record you can group by cocktail

```
db.temp.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$cocktail" },
    {
     "$group": {
             _id: {
                     "_id": "$_id",
                     items: {$addToSet: '$cocktail'}}
            }
        }
    }
 ] );
```

This should answer your 1st query

**For getting cocktail names** you need to use lookup, group and project something like this

```
db.temp.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$cocktail"       
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "cocktail ",
            "localField": "restaurant.cocktail._id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "cocktails"
        }
    },  
    { "$unwind": "$cocktails" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "cocktail": { "$cocktail": "$cocktail" },
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,  
            "coor" : 1,
            "cocktail.name" : 1,
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Note:**  This is just one approach, might not be the best way and also untested.

Answer (score 0):

what about using aggregation.

first perform match stage where you get all restaurant then perform unwind operation on cocktail after this you can perform group by on cocktail field. At this stage you have all unique cocktail id then perform lookup stage .

Order of stage

1. match
2. project if you want its optional
3. unwind
4. group
5. lookup
6. project //because you want only name of cocktail instead of complete
   collection.

The code is in kotlin just convert it to java if you are using intellij as ide then it will convert it into java for you.

```
var match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("address.location").withinSphere(Circle(latitude, longitude, radius / 6371)))
        var project = Aggregation.project("cocktail")
        var unwind = Aggregation.unwind("cocktail")
        var group = Aggregation.group("cocktail")
        var lookup = Aggregation.lookup("your cocktail collection name","_id.cocktail","id","cocktailCollection")
        var project1 = Aggregation.project("cocktailCollection.name").andExclude("_id")

    var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match,project,unwind,group,lookup,project1)

    println(aggregation) // if you want to see the query

    var result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,String::class.java)
```

Comment: TY for the answer, but unfortunately I'm new to MongoDB and I don't know how to translate what you just wrote to code.

Comment: I solvedo in this way


`List<ObjectId> restaurantList = mongoTemplate.findDistinct(
                new Query(
                        Criteria.where("address.location").withinSphere(new Circle(latitude, longitude, radius / 6371))
                ),
                "cocktailList",
                Restaurant.class,
                ObjectId.class
        );

        return cocktailRepository.findBy_idIn(new HashSet<>(restaurantList));`

Answer (score 0):

You can search data from two or more collection using join in MongoDB.
Depending on your scenario,the following links might help.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction